# How To Get The Correct Time Zone Offset (In And Out Of Daylight Savings)

Tags: .net, vb.net, timezone, dst

I found the following code from a website (sorry, I cannot remember the site now for references), however, it gave me the current time zone offset for my computer.  So for example, this code:

```
Dim plusminus As String = If((tz.Hours > 0), "+", "-")
Dim NewTimeZone As String = String.Format("{0}{1:00}:{2:00}", plusminus, Math.Abs(tz.Hours), tz.Minutes)
```

Gave me '+09:30' as an output.  Which was perfect.  However since daylight savings has come into affect, the same code now gives me '+10:30' which is in fact incorrect.

Can someone please advsise of a better method for retrieving the offset correctly (both in and out of daylight savings time) and returned in the same format (+09:30)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are relying on string types and thus there is nothing you can do (other than hardcoding as many modifying parameters as you wish). The logical thing while dealing with Dates/Times is relying on date/time types. If you use the adequate type you would have different options; for example, relying on different time zones (DayLight Savings is one of the properties of the given type): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  You only are showing the string formatting code - not how you obtained the `tz` variable.  What do you mean by "correct"?  You say that +10:30 is "incorrect" because it has DST - but most people would say that *not* applying DST would be incorrect.  What is your use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to find the difference between UTC and the current time irrespective of any daylight savings?

If I am correct then the following will do what you want:

```
Dim tzi As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local
Dim offset As TimeSpan = tzi.BaseUtcOffset
Dim plus As String = If(offset.TotalMinutes >= 0, "+", "")
Dim newTimeZone As String = String.Format("{0}{1:00}:{2:00}", plus, offset.Hours, offset.Minutes)
```

Outputs `+00:00` on my machine (my local time is UTC+1 but we are in DST currently)